# How to include several modules in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module, code-organization

I am uncertain about the way of including several modules into RSpec, so let me describe my situation.

Under `app/helpers` I have two files with helpers, containing the modules `ApplicationHelper` and `MailersHelper`. Although these are view helpers, which I use in my views and mails, I also use some of their methods in my tests, so they must by accessible within a `describe` clause.

Under `app/spec/mailers` I also have a file, containing the module `Helpers`. This module contains methods, that are only to be used in the tests (mostly wrapper methods for long expectations).

Additionally I have the following code:

```
class Helpers
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
end

def helper
  Helper.instance
end
```

It serves the purpose of making view helpers available in tests. Currently this code resides within the `Helper` module right before the wrapper methods, as they use the `Helper.instance` method.

I have three mailers, that I want to test. So how do I make all those things accessible in the tests?

#### Option 1

Use include directly under describe in each of the mailer specs like so:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyMailer do
  include ApplicationHelper
  include MailersHelper
  include Helpers
  ...
end
```

#### Option 2

In the file `helpers.rb` I do this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Helpers
  include MailersHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
  ...

end

RSpec.configure { |c| c.include Helpers }
```

and in each mailer spec I use `require_relative './helpers'`

#### Option 3

Like above but instead of including `ApplicationHelper` and `MailersHelper` in `Helpers`, I do this:

```
RSpec.configure do |c| 
  c.include Helpers
  c.include ApplicationHelper
  c.include MailersHelper
end
```

What I am so confused about is:

1. I do the RSpec.configure part in a separate file (`helpers.rb`), which I `require_relative` in my mailers specs. So this means these modules will be available only to my mailers specs, not to the whole suit, right? (As it would have been the case if I had done this in spec_helper.rb).
2. What is the best practice of organizing methods, which are not view helpers, but are helpers shared between several classes (mostly Controllers or Mailers). How should they be named, where should they be put?

Constant autoloading is really a hard topic for me - sometimes you get a module/class directly available and you don't need to do anything (but this might depend on the exact naming of your file/module), sometimes you must `require` it or `relative_require` it, but you must be careful where exactly you do this, because otherwise it will become globally available, and sometimes you have a special way of including things like with RSpec.configure... oh, boy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be done in `spec_helper.rb`. You can conditionally `include` modules depending on the spec type.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MailersHelper, type: :mailer
end
```

Any spec in `spec/mailers` will now automatically include `MailersHelper`.

You can trigger this manually by doing

```
RSpec.describe FooConstant, type: :mailer do
  # ... etc
end
```

in cases where the spec doesn't reside in `spec/mailers` but you want to treat it like one.